# Application Sharing in Adobe AIR

Tags: java, flash, air

Iam writing an Application Sharing application, my company has used to choose Adobe Air for this.

After Researching on google and posting on Adobe Forums , I found that AIR doesn't allow to access the OS natively. We need to create workarounds.

I have tried and implemented Merapi and tried using J2EE based server Queues and also tried using remoting.

But the application performance greatly reduces by all these workarounds.

I need to know if any body has implemented such a program in flash AS3 or flex or AIR. I know a company called as Spreed.com who has done that , Iam figuring on how they might have achieved that.

Can anybody give me some ideas on how to program this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have planned to use Play2p plugin for this application. Its a great plugin and works great with very good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly AIR(in it's current version, 1.5)is just a poor solution for something like this. A better bet would be a SWF wrapper application like MDM Zinc or North Code SWFStudio.

If you must stick with AIR, know that any solution you come up with will tie to sockets or LocalConnection and will require you install that half of the app separately.